# Give me a hand in building a function in Facebook Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, dom-events

I am trying to build a Facebook application in which I need to extract the id's of my friends who don't like a certain page.

Up to now I've extracted all my friend id's using the function below.

I need to generate a code which builds another API that uses the id of my friends to get their likes..

```
function loadFriends()
{
    //get array of friends
    FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
        console.log(response);
 var testdiv = document.getElementById("test");
        for(i=0;i<response.data.length;i++)
            {
                 testdiv.innerHTML +=  response.data[i].id + '<br/>' ;
            }
    });
}
```

I'll need to get something like :

```
 FB.api('/response.data[i].id/likes', function(response) {
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
FB.api({
            method: 'fql.query',
            query: 'SELECT first_name, last_name, pic_big FROM USER WHERE uid IN ( SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id=' + page_id + ' AND uid IN ( SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() ) )'
        }, function(response){

//you get the friends who liked this page. now you can remove these ids from friends lists to get you result.
});
```

Comment: Hi venu, Thanks for the reply.. i got this code here.. can you tell me why isn't it working?

FB.api(
  {
    method: 'fql.query',
            query: 'SELECT uid, first_name, pic_small FROM user WHERE uid IN(
 SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id='411133928921438' AND uid IN (
  SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()
 ))'

  },
  function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    var testdiv = document.getElementById("test");
    for (i=0; i<=response.length; i++) {
       testdiv.innerHTML += response.data[i].uid + '<br/>' ;
    }

}